# Using IComparer for sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, icomparer

I am trying to use an `IComparer` to sort a list of Points. Here is the IComparer class:

```
public class CoordinatesBasedComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(Object q, Object r)
    {
        Point a = (p)q;
        Point b = (p)r;
        if ((a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y))
            return 0;
        if ((a.x < b.x) || ((a.x == b.x) && (a.y < b.y)))
            return -1;

        return 1;
    }
}
```

In the client code, I am trying to using this class for sorting a list of points p (of type `List<Point>`):

```
CoordinatesBasedComparer c = new CoordinatesBasedComparer();
Points.Sort(c);
```

The code errors out. Apparently it is expecting `IComparer<Point>` as argument to sort method.
What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: What error are you getting? In what line?

Comment: Why don't you use LINQ, it's even faster with sorting.

Comment: @gdoron I'm not sure "faster" is the right term; *more convenient*, maybe

Comment: @MarcGravell, I tested it several times, FASTER. Think of it, with LINQ you know when the List is sorted while with `IComparer` you don't. Faster.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to implement the strongly type interface ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx)).

```
public class CoordinatesBasedComparer : IComparer<Point>
{
    public int Compare(Point a, Point b)
    {
        if ((a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y))
            return 0;
        if ((a.x < b.x) || ((a.x == b.x) && (a.y < b.y)))
            return -1;

        return 1;
    }
}
```

BTW, I think you use too many braces, I believe they should be used only when they contribute to the compiler. This is my version:

```
if (a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y)
    return 0;
if (a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y))
    return -1;
```

Just like I dislike people using `return (0)`.

---

Note that if you target a .Net-3.5+ application you can use LINQ which is easier and even faster with sorting.

LINQ vesion can be something like:

```
var orderedList = Points.OrderBy(point => point.x)
                        .ThenBy(point => point.y)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: When you say IComparer<Point> , doesn't Point stand as a placeholder variable value for which value has to be specified during instatiation? A little confused...if the class around which it works need not be specified at the client side, whats the point in having generic type?

Comment: @Aadith, you got me confused... No, the interface: `IComparer<T>` left you to chose with what of class you want to replace `T`, in your case you used `Point`. Just like when you create a Generic list of points: `List<Point>` which is `List<T>` when T is Point.

Comment: Be aware that the LINQ version is different from the non-LINQ version in that the `List<Point>` instance is replaced. If it is important that the list remains the *same* list, this should be noted.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper. Just like with every LINQ method, with the fact that I never encountered a problem with it, I don't feel any need specifying it unless explicitly demanded to remain the original `List<T>`.

Comment: @gdoron got it..the point i was missing was that my class is actually a client to IComparer..thanks!

Comment: >BTW, I think you use too many braces, I believe they should be used only when they contribute to the compiler.

Braces help avoid mistakes.  https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html

Comment: Curly braces exist for a reason: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/

Comment: Nice post.  But I disagree about braces.  If at some point you need to addd a second statement to the true condition, it will break if you don't have the braces.  I always use braces on if (and while etc.) statements, even if I put the result statement on the same line as the if like:  if (a == b) {return 0;}

Comment: I took a few minutes to acquaint myself with LINQ OrderBy (thanks for the suggestion) and I like it WAY better than using IComparer.

I had an array of Invoices (Invoice[] invoices) that I wanted to sort by a field called datePaid(newest first)  Here is my Code:

Invoice[] sortedInvoices = invoices.OrderByDescending(i => i.paidDate).ToArray<Invoice>();  

One and done.  I am a fan of strongly typed variables so I eschew var types.

Answer (score 14):

```
public class CoordinatesBasedComparer : IComparer, IComparer<Point>
{
    public int Compare(Point a, Point b)
    {
        if ((a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y))
            return 0;
        if ((a.x < b.x) || ((a.x == b.x) && (a.y < b.y)))
            return -1;

        return 1;
    }
    int IComparer.Compare(Object q, Object r)
    {
        return Compare((Point)q, (Point)r);            
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of implementing IComparer (the non-generic version) here, if all OP needs is the generic version?

Comment: @zmbq a: because when writing a comparer, you don't *know* who the caller is, and what they need. And b: because it is 1 line of actual code, plus a method signature

Comment: +1, Only out of curiosity: Have you used `IComparer, IComparer<Point>` since LINQ entered the game?(in .Net3.5\C#3...)

Answer (score 12):

If you're slow like me, the -1 and 1 can be difficult to reason about when using `IComparer`. The way to think about it is when `x` should go first, return -1. When `y` should go first, return 1.

It can still get confusing if you have lots of fields to sort by. You can use an `Enum` to make your comparison logic more readable than 1 and -1, then cast the result.

This example puts objects with the least amount of null fields in the front.

```
public class NullishObjectsToTheBackOfTheLine: IComparer<ClassToCompare>
{
    private enum Xy
    {
        X = -1,
        Both = 0,
        Y = 1
    };

    //the IComparer implementation wraps your readable code in an int cast.
    public int Compare(ClassToCompare x, ClassToCompare y)
    {
        return (int) CompareXy(x, y);
    }

    private static Xy CompareXy(ClassToCompare x, ClassToCompare y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return Xy.Both;

        //put any nulls at the end of the list
        if (x == null) return Xy.Y;
        if (y == null) return Xy.X;

        if (x.Country == y.Country && x.ProductId == y.ProductId) return Xy.Both;

        //put the least amount of at the front
        if (x.ProductId == null && x.Country == null) return Xy.Y;
        if (y.ProductId == null && y.Country == null) return Xy.X;

        //put the country values that are not nulls in front
        if (x.Country != y.Country) return x.Country != null ? Xy.X :  Xy.Y;

        //if we got this far, one of these has a null product id and the other doesn't
        return x.ProductId != null ? Xy.X : Xy.Y;
    }

}

public class ClassToCompare
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. 1 is for x > y and -1 when x < y. You can check it by calling CompareTo on int/double whatever.

Comment: Not wrong, that’s the same as saying “when x should go first, return -1. When y should go first, return 1.”

Comment: @ChadHedgock `If you're slow like me, the -1 and 1 can be difficult to reason about when using IComparer. The way to think about it is when x should go first, return -1. When y should go first, return 1.` . Mea culpa.  The resutls are the same, but the journey follows different approach.

Basicly what you do is sort from different side. Which I don't like. I just got mislead by this post.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an `InvalidOperation` error while adding an object of type `MyClass` to a `SortedList<MyClass>`. I was, incorrectly, implementing the IComparer interface. What I needed to implement was IComparable with the method CompareTo(MyClass other), instead of the ICompare.Compare(MyClass x, MyClass y). This is a simplified example:

```
SortedList<MyClass> sortedList = new SortedList<MyClass>();
MyClass a=new MyClass(), b=new MyClass();
sortedList.Add(a);
sortedList.Add(b); // Note, sort only happens once second element is added
```

**This fixed it**:

```
public class MyClass : IComparable<MyClass>
{
    int IComparable<MyClass>.CompareTo(MyClass other)
    {
        // DoCompareFunction(this, other); and return -1,0,1
    }
}
```

**This was broken (don't do this if adding to `SortedList<MyClass>`)**:

```
public class MyClass : IComparer<MyClass>
{
    int IComparable<MyClass>.Compare(MyClass x, MyClass y)
    {
        // DoCompareFunction(x, y); and return -1,0,1
    }
}
```

**This was the error:**

> Failed to compare two elements in the array.
>      at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.BinarySearch(T[] array,
>   Int32 index, Int32 length, T value, IComparer`1 comparer)
>      at System.Array.BinarySearch[T](T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, T
>   value, IComparer`1 comparer)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)