# rearrange a list of objects by type field in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, linq

I have an incoming list of alerts and I use a MapFunction as:

```
private static BPAlerts MapToAlerts(List<IntakeAlert> intakeAlerts)
        {
            // Make sure that there are alerts
            if (intakeAlerts.IsNullOrEmpty()) return new BPAlerts { AllAlerts = new List<BPAlert>(), OverviewAlerts = new List<BPAlert>() };

            // All Alerts
            var alerts = new BPAlerts
            {
                AllAlerts = intakeAlerts.Select(
                    alert => new BPAlert
                    {
                        AlertTypeId = alert.AlertTypeId ?? 8100,
                        IsOverview = alert.IsOverviewAlert.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        Text = alert.AlertText,
                        Title = alert.AlertTitle,
                        Type = alert.AlertTypeId == 8106 ? "warning" : "report",
                        Severity = alert.AlertSeverity.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        Position = alert.Position.GetValueOrDefault()
                    }).OrderBy(a => a.Position).ToList()
            };


            // Alerts displayed on the overview page
            alerts.OverviewAlerts =
                alerts.AllAlerts
                    .ToList()
                    .Where(a => a.IsOverview && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Title))
                    .Take(3)
                    .ToList();

            return alerts;
        }
```

the BPAlerts type contains list of two type:

```
 public class BPAlerts
    {
        public List<BPAlert> AllAlerts { get; set; }
        public List<BPAlert> OverviewAlerts { get; set; }
    }
```

And the BPAlert type is defined as:

```
 public class BPAlert
    {
        public short AlertTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Severity { get; set; }
        public bool IsOverview { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; internal set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
```

I want to achieve a task in which the MaptoAlerts function returns a alerts object with overviewalerts which are sorted based on the type of BPAlert. To be more clear in the following order if present:

Confirmed Out of Business - 8106 \n
Bankruptcy - 8105 \n
Lack of Licensing - 8111 \n
Investigations - 8109 \n
Government Actions - 8103 \n
Pattern of Complaints - 8104 \n
Customer Reviews - 8112 \n
Accreditation - 8110 \n
Misuse of BBB Name - 8101 \n
Advisory - 8107 \n
Advertising Review – 8102 \n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution #1 Order values array

I would just define the order of those ids in some kind of collection, can be an array:

```cs
var orderArray = new int[]
{
    8106,   // Confirmed Out of Busine
    8105,   // Bankruptcy
    8111,   // Lack of Licensing
    8109,   // Investigations
    8103,   // Government Actions
    8104,   // Pattern of Complaints
    8112,   // Customer Reviews
    8110,   // Accreditation
    8101,   // Misuse of BBB Name
    8107,   // Advisory
    8102,   // Advertising Review
};
```

Then iterate through array while incrementing order value. While looping check if order array contains actual type id which order value I'm trying to evaluate:

```cs
for (int orderValue = 0; orderValue < orderArray.Length; orderValue++)
{
    if (alertTypeId == orderArray[orderValue])
    {
        return orderValue;
    }
}
```

If not found in the array, return highest value possible:

```cs
return int.MaxValue
```

Whole method would look like this and it would evaluate the order for alert type id:

```cs
public int GetAlertTypeIdOrder(short alertTypeId)
{
    var orderArray = new int[]
    {
        8106,   // Confirmed Out of Busine
        8105,   // Bankruptcy
        8111,   // Lack of Licensing
        8109,   // Investigations
        8103,   // Government Actions
        8104,   // Pattern of Complaints
        8112,   // Customer Reviews
        8110,   // Accreditation
        8101,   // Misuse of BBB Name
        8107,   // Advisory
        8102,   // Advertising Review
    };

    for (int orderValue = 0; orderValue < orderArray.Length; orderValue++)
    {
        if (alertTypeId == orderArray[orderValue])
        {
            return orderValue;
        }
    }

    return int.MaxValue;
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var sortedAlerts = alerts
    .AllAlerts
    .OrderByDescending(a => GetAlertTypeIdOrder(a.AlertTypeId))
    .ToList();
```

It also works in a descending way.

#### Solution #2 Order values dictionary

You could achieve better performance by reducing the redundancy - repeated creation of array storing order values. Better idea would be to store the order rules in a dictionary. I know that code below creates an array too, but the concept is that it would be called once to get the dictionary which would be then passed over.

```cs
public Dictionary<int, int> GetOrderRules()
{
    var alertTypeIds = new int[]
    {
        8106,   // Confirmed Out of Busine
        8105,   // Bankruptcy
        8111,   // Lack of Licensing
        8109,   // Investigations
        8103,   // Government Actions
        8104,   // Pattern of Complaints
        8112,   // Customer Reviews
        8110,   // Accreditation
        8101,   // Misuse of BBB Name
        8107,   // Advisory
        8102,   // Advertising Review
    };

    var orderRules = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    for (int orderValue = 0; orderValue < alertTypeIds.Length; orderValue++)
    {
        orderRules.Add(alertTypeIds[orderValue], orderValue);
    }

    return orderRules;
}
```

So the `GetAlertIdOrder()` method would look different, but still keeping the idea from previous solution:

```cs
public int GetAlertIdOrder(short alertTypeId, IDictionary<int, int> orderRules)
{
    if (orderRules.TryGetValue(alertTypeId, out int orderValue))
    {
        return orderValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var orderRules = GetOrderRules();
var sortedAlerts = alerts
    .AllAlerts
    .OrderBy(a => GetAlertIdOrder(a.AlertTypeId, orderRules))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Good ideas here.  I would change GetAlertIdOrder to use tryParse (or check that they value is on the collection), over catching an exception.  Catching exception is expensive, relatively speaking.

Comment: @granadacoder Were you thinking about `TryGetValue()`? See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes.  The pattern is one thing.  The syntax varies (upvote for correcting this).  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exceptions-and-performance

Answer (score 1):

(a) I wouldn't mix sorting with the mapper.  let the mapper just do its thing. (this is separation of concerns ) .. aka,  no ordering/sorting.   IMHO, you'll always end up with way too much voodoo in the mapper that is hard to understand.  You're already on this path with the above code.

(b) if "OverviewAlerts" is a subset of AllAlerts (aka, AllAlerts is the superset), then hydrate AllAlerts, and create a read-only "get" property where you filter AllAlerts to your subset by its rules.  optionally, consider a AllAlertsSorted get property.  this way, you allow your consumers to choose if they want raw or sorted...since there is a cost with sorting.

```
public class BPAlerts
    {
        public List<BPAlert> AllAlerts { get; set; }

        public List<BPAlert> OverviewAlerts {
            get
                {
                    return null == this.AllAlerts ? null : this.AllAlerts.Where (do you filtering and maybe sorting here ) ; 
                } 
            }
    }

        public List<BPAlert> AllAlertsSorted{
            get
                {
                    return null == this.AllAlerts ? null : this.AllAlerts.Sort(do you filtering and maybe sorting here ) ; 
                } 
            }
    }
```

if you do the read-only properties, then you have more simple linq operations like

```
OrderBy(x => x.PropertyAbc).ThenByDescending(x => x.PropertyDef);
```

99% of my mapping code looks like this.  I don't even throw an error if you give null input, i just return null.

```
public static class MyObjectMapper {

    public static ICollection < MyOtherObject > ConvertToMyOtherObject(ICollection <MyObjectMapper> inputItems) {

        ICollection <MyOtherObject> returnItems = null;

        if (null != inputItems) {
            returnItems = new List <MyOtherObject> ();

            foreach(MyObjectMapper inputItem in inputItems) {

                MyOtherObject moo = new MyOtherObject();
                /* map here */
                returnItems.Add(moo);
            }
        }

        return returnItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: only problem is that when you see my sort logic. It is not by ascending or descending values of type. types being:  8106 Bankruptcy - 8105 Lack of Licensing - 8111 Investigations - 8109 Government Actions - 8103 Pattern of Complaints - 8104 Customer Reviews - 8112 Accreditation - 8110 Misuse of BBB Name - 8101 Advisory - 8107 Advertising Review – 8102

Comment: Then all the more reason to keep the mapper clean.  And write a custom IComparer to do your sort.        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336416/using-icomparer-for-sorting

Comment: I don't understand much of the code here as C# is not my forte. Can you simplify with comments please?

Comment: Basically, you write a new class to handle Sorting.   IComparer<YourObject> and then you can put any of your custom sort rules there.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__

Comment: Do we still need to hydrate by get?

Comment: or simply call that method on the returned object of my MapAlerts function?

Comment: the "get" properties are simply helpers to allow your consumers to have precanned functionality.  they are optional....in the sense, your consumers can always write their own sorting against the unsorted AllItems.

Comment: Can you help me with the/* map */ here logic ? I seem to not understand why mapping is necessary in this case? can we just not take that list, sort or rearrange it based on this wild logic and move ahead?

Comment: you can sort it simpler by index of list
this example should be clear:

 List<int> orderBy = new List<int>(){5,3,7,9,1, 8,2};
 List<int> list = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
 list.OrderBy(o=> (orderBy.Contains(o))? 0: 1).ThenBy(o=> orderBy.IndexOf(o));

Comment: AlertTypeId = alert.AlertTypeId ?? 8100,
                        IsOverview = alert.IsOverviewAlert.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        Text = alert.AlertText,
                        Title = alert.AlertTitle,
                        Type = alert.AlertTypeId == 8106 ? "warning" : "report",
                        Severity = alert.AlertSeverity.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        Position = alert.Position.GetValueOrDefault()    << all of this is your mapping logic

Comment: slightly rewritten        moo.AlertTypeId = alert.AlertTypeId ?? 8100;    (etc, etc)

Comment: Please read about separation of concerns.      https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/     Let's say 6 months from now, you need a different sort.  If you put it all in teh one method/function, you now are risking the integrity of the mapping (one concern) vs the sorting ( a second /different concern).

Comment: Power Mouse gives a decent example of how to do some non-standard ordering.